# I can't seem to shake this fastlane issue on GitHub actions: " Your Ruby version is 3.0.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.7"

Tags: ruby, github-actions, fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

I have been building my mobile pipelines both react-native and flutter pretty much the normal way. I am trying to get this first time fastlane pipeline up and so far it's been a bit rough. It's a react-native project with both android and iOS folders. I am following this blog  https://blog.logrocket.com/fastlane-build-test-ship-react-native-apps/ so my setup is similar. Just that I am doing a firebase distribution lane. On the GitHub action, the `actions/setup-ruby@v1` has been replaced by `ruby/setup-ruby@v1`.

The build always fails with the following even when a set like : ruby --version still shows `2.7.7`

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.7/x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.27/lib/bundler/definition.rb:441:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 3.0.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.7
```

[image: github action error]

Been scratching my hair for the past few hours on what I could be possibly doing wrong. Below is the GitHub actions

```
name: Android developer build

on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - feat/splitting-dev-from-uat-builds
      # - develop*
      # - feat/*

jobs:
  android-build:
    name: Android Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev
    steps:
      - name: Checkout 
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 8

      - name: Install npm dependencies
        run: |
          yarn install
      
      - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '2.7'

      - name: Checking Ruby Component versions
        run: |
          ruby --version
          # gem install bundler
          # gem install fastlane
  
      # # Install the Firebase app distribution plugin with fastlane
      # - name: Install Firebase app distribution plugin
      #   run: bundle exec fastlane add_plugin firebase_app_distribution

      # Create a keystore file out of it's base64 string version from secrets
      - name: Recreate android key store file
        id: write_keysotre_file
        uses: timheuer/base64-to-file@v1.2
        with:
          fileName: ${{ vars.DEV_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_NAME }}
          fileDir: ${{ vars.DEV_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_FOLDER_PATH }}
          encodedString: ${{ secrets.DEV_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_BASE64_FILE }}

      - name: distribute to firebase
        run: bundle exec fastlane android alpha
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_CLI_TOKEN }}
          FIREBASE_APP_ID: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_APP_ID }}
          ANDROID_KEYSTORE_FILE: ${{ vars.DEV_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_FOLDER_PATH }}/${{ vars.DEV_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_NAME }}
          ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DEV_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD }}
          ANDROID_KEYSTORE_KEY_ALIAS: ${{ secrets.DEV_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_KEY_ALIAS }}
          FIREBASE_DIST_GROUP: dev-android
```

The main Fastfile looks like the following

```
platform :android do
desc "This is a dev release, we will call it alpha"

    lane :alpha do
        increment_version_code(app_project_dir:'./android/app')
        increment_version_name(app_project_dir: './android/app', bump_type: 'patch')
        gradle(task: 'clean',project_dir: './android')
        gradle(task: 'assemble', bundle_type: 'Release', project_dir: './android', properties:{
            "android.injected.signing.store.file" => ENV['ANDROID_KEYSTORE_FILE'],
            "android.injected.signing.store.password" => ENV['ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD'],
            "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => ENV['ANDROID_KEYSTORE_KEY_ALIAS']   
    })
        output_path = "./android/app/build/outputs/apk/"

        firebase_app_distribution(
            app: ENV['FIREBASE_APP_ID'],
            firebase_cli_token: ENV['FIREBASE_CLI_TOKEN'],
            groups: ENV['FIREBASE_DIST_GROUP'],
            release_notes: "Git commit: #{last_git_commit[:abbreviated_commit_hash]}",
        )
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you try running `gem install bundler` and `bundle install` after setting up Ruby?

Comment: See https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby#bundler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This didn't make much differences. I will need to really understand how ruby and package management and build tools works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to deep dive you can try to change ruby version to 3.0.2 in your actions file or in your .ruby-version file and Gemfile

Comment: I had to use this method by sacrificing the discovery of what exactly might be the problem aspect. I am too behind to want to give deep. Thanks for the hint.